# Setting a range between a starting cell and the first empty cell in the column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to write a script that selects a starting cell based on a search input, and then sets the range between the starting cell and the last cell before an empty cell.

At the moment this is what I have (the search script is separate, but it functions fine and selects the correct starting cell):

```
Dim PDFfiles As Range
Dim PDFfile As Variant
Dim n As Long
Dim rngFileStart, rngFileEnd As Variant
Dim StCell As Variant

  
'Set start point of cell range
'Takes ActiveCell from search results and offsets to filepaths

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PRODUCT REGISTER")
        
        Set StCell = ActiveCell
                
        Set rngFileStart = Range("D6:D18")
    
        

        Set rngFileEnd = rngFileStart.Find(What:=Empty, After:="D6", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, Searchdirection:=xlNext)
        

        Set PDFfiles = .Range(rngFileStart, rngFileEnd - 1)
   
        
    End With`
```

It is failing at the last line, as rngFileEnd returns as nothing. Just wondering where I am going wrong and why it is not returning a value to use in setting my PDFfiles range.

Comment: [ActiveCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activecell) is only one cell, so `rngFileStart` is also only one (non-empty) cell, so `rngFileEnd` is nothing.

Comment: Is this referring to using  ` rngFileStart ` as the expression in the Range.Find? Even if I change the whole line to use manual cells it doesn't work. I have updated the original post with this code to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
 Set rngFileEnd = rngFileStart.Find( _
      What:=Empty, _
      After:="D6", _
      LookIn:=xlValues, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      Searchdirection:=xlNext)
```

the `After` parameter needs to refer to a single cell.

Using `"D6"` refers to the *string* "D6" and *not* the cell.

Use any of:

```
      After:=Range("D6")

      After:=[D6]

      After:=Cells(6,4)
```

instead.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-cells-by-using-shortcut-notation